# Pointwise and uniform convergence of series of funtions.

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence

If I understand it right, uniform convergence by sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ means, that there is a limit function $F$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can always chose a high enough $n_0$ (the lower index of the function) such that for every $n > n_0$ and for every $x$, $f_n(x)$ is closer to the limit function (at corresponding $x$) than $\epsilon$.

I have a simple example on the domain $[-1, 1]$. The function sequence is $f_n(x) = x^{2n}$.

Now the limit function is: $f(x) = 1$ if $x=\pm 1$ , $0$ else.

They say the sequence converges only pointwise to the limit function. Why? I can choose whatever $\epsilon$, I just take a high enough $n$ and the every $x$ will be made very small close enough to $0$. And if $x=$1 then the limit function is equal to any member of the function sequence, so it is within the $\epsilon$ range too. Can you please explain this for me? Thank you!

Comment: Are you requiring uniform convergence as a continuous function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I am asking why is this example not uniformly convergent.

Comment: It's because your definition of uniform convergence is incorrect. You are given $\epsilon>0$ and you need to pick $n_0$ that works for *every* $x$ in the domain. That is why we call it uniform: because it has to work for everything at once. Also, note that your example has no limit at $x=-1$ as the sequence goes $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$

Comment: @James, yes right, it should be 2n exactly out of this reason, I correct it.
But I don't get your answer. Here it works for every x if we chose a high enough n. I am obviously mistaken here but I don't see why...

Comment: (and I don't know how to edit it to be x to the 2n)

Comment: use x^{2n} for that

Comment: This is the classical beginner's mistake, many students make it. The trouble with your argument is that $n_0$ will depend on $x$: the further you go towards the endpoints, the larger is has to be, in such a way that in the end you will not be able to find any fixed $n_0$ (i.e. not depending on $x$) that will be good in every point $x$.

Comment: As Alex notes below, if a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to some $f$, then $f$ is continuous. No one is going to work out the epsilon and deltas for you. How about you try to actually find $n_0$ for $\epsilon = 1/4$?

Comment: ok I start to get it, but not fully jet. So here is a 'competition': I say a very big n, but then you say an x very close to +-1 for that applies x to the n is not less then epsilon, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: Each $f_n$ is continuous at 1. This means that there is some interval $(x_n,1]$, so that $f_n$  is greater than $3/4$ on $(x_n,1]$. Note that $x_n<1$ for each $n$.

Now if $f_n$ converged uniformly to $f$ (as defined in your question), then we would be able to pick some $n_0$ so that for each $n>n_0$ the $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<1/4$ for each $x \in [-1,1]$. Yet, for each $n$, on $(x_n,1)$ the difference $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |f_n(x)-0|>3/4$. So we can't *ever* pick a large enough $n_0$ so that for every $n>n_0$, $f_n$ is within $1/4$ of $f$. Hence the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: ok, this gave the right picture into my head. Of course thanks for Alex too, now I got your answer too.

Answer (score 2):

The quick proof is the following: if a sequence of *continuous* functions converges *uniformly* to some limit function, then this limit function will also be continuous. In your case, your functions are continuous but the limit is not, therefore the convergence cannot be uniform.

If you require a "proof with $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$", nobody will have the patience to write that down...

**Edit:**

Okay, since you really want to understand this, let's try a not entirely rigurous but very visual explanation.

Fix an $\varepsilon$. Choose some interval $[-r_1, r_1] \subset [-1, 1]$. You can find a number $n_1$ such that (using your own notations) $|f_n - f| < \varepsilon$ on $[-r_1, r_1]$ for all $n \geq n_1$.

Now, if you strech your interval $[-r_1, r_1]$ attempting to cover the whole $[-1, 1]$ (i.e. you make $r_1 \to 1$), you will discover that there is a $r_1 < r_2 \leq 1$ such that $n_1$ is no longer good on $[-r_2, r_2]$ (i.e. it is too small). So, you replace it by a *larger* $n_2$.

You repeat the whole procedure with an even larger interval $[-r_3, r_3]$, and you discover that $n_2$ is no longer good for this interval, so you replace it by an *even larger* $n_3$ and so on.

The larger your interval is (i.e. the closer its endpoints are to $-1$ and $1$), the larger your $n_0$ will have to be - and this game accelerates the closer you get to $\pm 1$. By now you've probably guessed: by the time you reach $\pm 1$, your $n_0$ will also have reached $\infty$, which is no longer a natural number.

Comment: That's true, if you need a prove with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ you have to find a bound for the function which doesn't depend to x, and then have that bound converge to 0. In this case it's easier just checking that the properties of uniformly convergent functions don't work.

Comment: ok, I don't want to misuse your patience in the first place, and luckily i don't need a proof. I want to understand it. Maybe we can turn it around. Name an epsilon where you cannot give a high enough n for this: |fn(x)-f(x)| is smaller than epsilon.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort,  I got it! Too bad I can't accept two answers... :/